# How can I directly negate options in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

For instance, to get all network addresses/adapters in order to apply settings to them:

```
Get-NetIPAddress | Set-NetIPAddress -SkipAsSource $true
```

Except, I need to exempt one of them. The list is long so the best way to do it would be singling it out, more or less`Get-NetIPAddress -ifIndex 39 | Set-NetIPAddress -SkipAsSource…` but negated.

I know I can use `if`, `Where-Object`, or whatever, but the point is to do it shortly like you can do in Bash with just `!`. This is why I phrased it as negating *options* rather than *conditions*.

I tried:

```
Get-NetIPAddress -ifIndex !39
Get-NetIPAddress -ifIndex -ne 39
Get-NetIPAddress (! -ifIndex 39)
Get-NetIPAddress !(-ifIndex 39)
Get-NetIPAddress -ifIndex not 39
```

I wasn't expecting them to work since, some of them are borrowed syntax from the other functions(?). You don't bother typing the command without a little bit of hope it'll work though.

Thanks.

Comment: You must do it the Powershell way, not the Bash way: `Get-NetIPAddress | ? { $_.InterfaceIndex -ne 25 }` or shorter `Get-NetIPAddress | ? { $_.IfIndex -ne 25 }` . You can even create an alias for Get-NetIPAddress to make shorter.

Answer (score 1):

The standard PowerShell option parser does not have a generic "negation" syntax because it's an *option* parser, not a *filter* parser (even if some the options happen to be used for the purpose of filtering, but that happens long after the options and their values been parsed) – boolean "flag" options can be negated, but "value" options cannot.

(You can't really do it in "Bash" either; `find ! -foo` only works because the `find` command specifically uses a custom command-line parser that has been designed for that, but this does not apply to any other program, certainly not the ones using a generic getopt_long `--option` parser.)

The cmdlet *could* recognize `!` as part of the option value (e.g. `Get-NetIPAddress -ifIndex !39`), but again, hasn't been programmed that way. (It probably requests ifIndex to be parsed as an integer.)

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell does accept the `!` operator as a alternative syntax
for the `not` operator, although only in the context of a boolean
expression, so not with parameters.

For example, you may write :

```
if (-Not (Test-Path C:\Code)) {
    write "it doesn't exist!"
}
```

But you may also use `!` this way:

```
if (!(Test-Path C:\Code)) { write "it doesn't exist!" }
```

User @ReddyLutonadio has indicated in his comment various methods for
formulating your example command with the shortest possible syntax.